# Real valued continuous function on arbitrary space

Tags: continuity

I was wondering if we can construct a continuous function $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is not the constant function. Here X is an arbitrary infinite set with some metric d defined on it. The metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is the euclidean metric. I am solving a problem where I need to use the fact that such a function exists but I have no clue where to begin.

Edit: I have modified the problem to include a metric d on X.

Comment: Your question is very large. What is $X$? Talking about continuity requires a topology on $X$. If no topology is mentioned, there can be no answer

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. So a topology is necessarily required?

Comment: If $X$ is an arbitrary set and You equip it with the trivial topology, the constant functions are the only continuous ones

Answer (score 2):

Fix some $a \in X$.  Then $f(x) = d(a,x)$ is a real-valued continuous function on $X$, which is non-constant if $X$ has more than one member.

Comment: Ahh. I should have been able to do this. So simple!

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hi professor Israel, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695457/if-q-is-a-rectangle-and-if-d-subseteq-q-is-the-set-of-points-where-fq-righ)?